# OrangeHRM Custom Fields

Tags: field, orangehrm

I am trying to change the number of custom fields I can create in OrgangeHRM PIM section.

I have found a few articles on this site that say what part of the code to change but non saying where to find the file where the code is stored is in.

If anyone can help then that would be great.

I am running version 4.0 of OrangeHRM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

orangeHRM have slots for custom field (i dont remember, but i think 10 slot in orange 4.0), you can use this for put what you need.

Out the box, you can follow guides for add more custom or pre-format fields, but not is more recomendable, this can make broken code.

meanwhile, you think work out the box, remember orangeHRM is a symfony based software, if you know how work symfony (MVC framework), work it whit OrangeHRM is more easy

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the help